# update cscope db from vim

Tags: vim, cscope

I use cscope with vim.
When doing large edits for several files, cscope will report old line numbers for changed files. 
How can I rebuild cscope db from vim without losing

- opened tabs/windowses in vim
- connection with cscope engine

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_create_and_update_cscope_database

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, you need to update cscope database.

```
:!cscope -Rbq
```

Then, reinit the database from vim.

```
:cs reset
```

Comment: When there is an existing connection to the cscope database `cscope.out`, cscope creates another one `ncscope.out`. How to replace the old database? I am using a Windows cscope port.

Comment: error: "cscope: -q option mismatch between command line and old symbol database"

Answer (score 9):

Building on a previous answer, add this to your .vimrc:

```
map <F5> :!cscope -Rb<CR>:cs reset<CR><CR>
```

Then use F5 within vim to do the refresh.

-b = Build cross-reference only.
-R = Recurse subdirectories during search for source files.

Answer (score 4):

## [cscope_dynamic](https://github.com/erig0/cscope_dynamic)

cscope_dynamic does all you ask, and even more:

- autoloads the database when you open vim.
- loads the local cscope database if it exists, instead of the global one.
- gracefully handles the connection
- automatically saves changes to database
- it is much much faster, especially when working with large source base

### How is it faster?

It uses two databases:

- **small database:** it is updated frequently, with small changes, so it is really fast
- **big database:** it is updated less frequently by merging the small database into this one.

---

**Edit:** Feb17:
*Removed old answer as cscope_dynamic does all these out of the box.*

Answer (score 2):

I use a script that keeps building my indexes in the background:

```
" We need to setup the function that reset cscope.
"You could define this in your vimrc instead.
vim --servername GVIM --remote-send ":function! ResetCscope()<CR>cscope reset<CR>endfunction<CR>"

while true ; do
    echo building...

    ctags -R
    cscope -Rbk
    vim --servername VIM --remote-expr "ResetCscope()"

    echo done. sleeping.
    sleep 1m
done
```

(It's actually [a lot](https://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/blob/master/unix/scripts/continuous_build.sh) more [complicated](https://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/blob/master/multi/vim/.vim/scripts/build_alttagfiles.sh) than that.)

The vim call should reload the cscope database in vim if you started it with `vim --servername VIM`. (I use a [background command](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) to run cscope queries, so I'm not sure about this. The command launches cscope independently and doesn't use Vim's connection.)

Comment: Oops. I forgot that since I use enormous cscope databases that take seconds to search, I rarely call vim's cscope commands directly. I've updated the answer to reset the cscope connection.

Answer (score 2):

Tried this recently in gVim 8.0 on Windows, but even after the cs reset, vim was locking cscope.out so cs could not regenerate cscope.out with vim open.

In this case, I added the following additional mapping (F12 in e.g) which kills the current cscope connection so cscope can regenerate the cscope.out with F11, without having to close the vim. Hope this helps some one.

```
map <F11> :!cscope -Rbq<CR><ESC>:cs add cscope.out<CR><CR> 
map <F12> :cs kill cscope.out<CR><CR>
```